# Scrolling even when mouse leaves the browser window?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

An observation regarding the official jScrollPane [full page scroll demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html)...

Click and drag the large vertical scrollbar controlling the window. I've noticed the following behavior when you click+drag the scrollbar and the mouse accidentally leaves the browser window:

- Safari(XP): The scrollbar responds even when dragging outside of the browser window. Can't seem to break it. Awesome.
- FF4(XP): The scrollbar stops responding. It responds again successfully when the mouse re-enters (you don't have to click to start dragging again). Slightly annoying.
- IE8(XP): The scrollbar stops responding. It doesn't respond when the mouse re-enters either (you have to click to drag again). This is the worst of the three.

So Safari (and Webkit, I presume) handles mouse movement outside the window perfectly. Is it even possible to get IE and FF to behave similarly, or are those limitations of the Trident and Gecko engines?

Answer (score 1):

[I originally answered [a completely different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310654/jquery-jscrollpane-on-ul/6329440) here by mistake so editing to answer the correct question]

There is very little jScrollPane can do about this. I did a little research but it seems that different browsers behave differently when it comes to triggering rollout/mouseout events when the mouse leaves the browser window. This makes it hard to implement a consistent behaviour within jScrollPane (the problem also occurs when the mouse leaves an iframe if you use full body scroll on an iframe).

I think there are probably security reasons for browsers not reporting mouse movement outside of the window so there is probably very little that can be done about this :(

Comment: What? I'm not using any UL's or hidden elements. I linked to an official demo as the example. Did you mean to reply to a different thread?

Comment: Yes I did! Sorry about the confusion! I'll replace the answer above with something actually relevant to your question!

Comment: No worries, thanks for your reply!
That's what I was worried about. Oh well. I can live with that. :)