# jQuery, jScrollPane on UL

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, html-lists

I cannot make this work for some reason.

I want jscrollpane to be used in an unordered list (ul).

I have managed to do this by itself but when used with a nested ul it does not seem to work.
I have uploaded my example to jsFiddle so anyone can take a look and fiddle around.

You can have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/44db/eAX8b/

Comment: it has come to my attention that because the ul is hidden when jscrollpane fires it does not work. I'm currently testing this issue and will come back when I have results.

Answer (score 6):

I posted this answer yesterday but on the [wrong question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309250/scrolling-even-when-mouse-leaves-the-browser-window/6316343)!

Here it is on the right question:

You shouldn't apply jScrollPane directly to a UL. Because jScrollPane needs to add additional markup to your page (to represent the scroll track etc) it will result in invalid HTML if you do. Instead you should wrap your UL in e.g. a div and apply jScrollPane to that.

Additionally, when I look at your example it appears that you are using jScrollPane on elements which are initially hidden. If this is the case then you will need to reinitialise jScrollPane after showing the elements like in this example:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/invisibles.html